# Exporting Image/Text files with JAR

Tags: java, image, jar, embedded-resource, executable-jar

So I have seen this question everywhere but I can't seem to understand the answer. Right now my code for importing an image looks like this:

```
private Image dirt = new ImageIcon("res/Dirt.png").getImage();
```

It takes the image Dirt.png from a folder called res housed in my project main folder. This works fine in Eclipse, but when exported I need to house the exported JAR along with the entire res folder in a larger folder on my desktop or else it fails to find my files.

So I have seen this sort of code snippet several times but don't know how to implement it into my code.

```
getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("file.txt")
```

I'm assuming some variable is assigned to this but once again I am unsure of this. Any help would be extremely helpful.

Also for my original code I wrote out the entire directory (C:/...) and the file was exported with my JAR, but as expected, this did not work on another computer.

Comment: While using `getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("res/Dirt.png")` what problems you have encountered?

Comment: Look at the [embedded resource info. page](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/embedded-resource/info) for tips, but use `getResource` for an `URL` - it is a more predictable method.

Comment: @AndrewThompson
Ok, so for my above code would it look like this?
URL url = this.getClass().getResource("res/dirt.png");
If so would I need to do a different URL for each image/text file I use?

Comment: *"If so would I need to do a different URL for each image/text file I use?"*  If you have 4 images, and need to access all 4, there will be 4 URLs.  I thought that was intuitively obvious.  BTW - usually `("res/Dirt.png")` should be `("/res/Dirt.png")`

Comment: I wasn't sure if you could load them all or even just the res folder into one URL. I did try the first / but then I got errors. Also, how can I extract the image from the URL?

Comment: *"how can I extract the image from the URL?"*  Most methods for loading a `File` or `InputStream` can also accept an `URL`.  There is also [`URL.openStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29) to get an `InputStream` instance.

Comment: I still don't understand how to get this to work in my code. I made a URL according to my first comment but still don't know how to get the image from it. I get my images directly from the code I showed in my question.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure that all of the resources are in the main project folder for when you export it. Assuming that they are you need to make sure that when you export it you should be given the option to include everything in the jar that is being exported.